# Is there any method to sleep in javascript in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, there is for loop that I want to sleep for some seconds.

```
$.each(para.res, function (index, item) {
    Sleep(100);
});
```

I know I can use setTimeout or setInterval but both of them are asychronous, the loop will continue, just the function in the setTimeout will run in a few seconds if I do it this way.

```
$.each(para.res, function (index, item) {
    setTimeOut(function(){do something},1000); 
});
```

Comment: if you apply sleep in javascript then your javascript will hang and user would not be happy

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: yes, i know i just want to do some animation, and i know the delay, but implementation of delay make story difficult.

Comment: Almost every time I've been tempted to do so I fixed it using a callback function. What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: could you show me what the callback means, just a simple exmaple

Comment: @john Rather than giving a function X seconds to finish, you instruct it to warn you when it has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function.

```
var i = 0;    
function recursive() {
  setTimeout(function(){
     var item = para.res[i];
     // do something
     i++;        
     if (i < para.res.length) recursive()
  }, 100)
}
```

Comment: Note that this will move the entire loop into the background.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built in method for that. You could use a busy loop, but that will freeze the browser in the mean time, and you can't do it for too long because then the browser will stop the script.

If you want the different pieces of code spread out over time, just set different times for `setTimeout`:

```
$.each(para.res, function (index, item) {
  setTimeOut(function(){do something},1000 * index); 
});
```

This will start the code for the first item after one second, the code for the second item after two seconds, and so on.

Or use `setInterval`:

```
var index = 0, timer = setInterval(function(){
  if (index < para.res.length) {
    var item = para.res[index];
    // do something
    index++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```