# Sleeping in an infinite loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program which should randomly change the position of a cross in a table every half a second forever, but I can't find a way to make the program wait for half a second without it hanging.

The following is my code, where the `sleep(0.5)` should be switched with something different:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="0x0">X</td>
            <td id="1x0">X</td>
            <td id="2x0">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="0x1">X</td>
            <td id="1x1">X</td>
            <td id="2x1">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="0x2">X</td>
            <td id="1x2">X</td>
            <td id="2x2">X</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        for(;;) {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

            id = x.toString() + "x" + y.toString();         
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "O";               
            sleep(0.5);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AndrewIce Please refer to http://w3fools.com and stop spamming! `:P` Reference to http://w3schools.com is considered spam.

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: [Is there any method to sleep in javascript in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12230612/218196).

Answer (score 3):

Javascript don't have function named `sleep`, but you can use `setTiemout` to execute a function after given time interval.

I'll also recommend you to use `setInterval` instead of infinite for loop to execute set of commands after specified time interval.

Another thing is that you're using `floor` on the random value, which will always be either `0` or `1` and it'll be never `2`. Use `Math.round` to round off the value to the nearest number. So it'll select all the values.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var x = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
  var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

  id = x.toString() + "x" + y.toString();
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "O";

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";
  }, 500);
}, 100);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="0x0">X</td>
    <td id="1x0">X</td>
    <td id="2x0">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="0x1">X</td>
    <td id="1x1">X</td>
    <td id="2x1">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="0x2">X</td>
    <td id="1x2">X</td>
    <td id="2x2">X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead of `sleep`:

```
function doSomething () {

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

    id = x.toString() + "x" + y.toString();         
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "O";               

    setTimeout(doSomething, 500);

}
```

Or a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) way:

```
setInterval(function () {

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

    id = x.toString() + "x" + y.toString();         
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "O";               

}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

could be easier to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) which will call a function for you every x thousandths of a second.

```
setInterval(function(){
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
   id = x.toString() + "x" + y.toString();         
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "O";               
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";
}, 500);
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question, OP want to wait for half second after setting the value and then want to reset the value again please check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use javascript's [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function instead. So, if you wanted your code to say, print something out every 10 seconds you'd do something like this:

```
window.setInterval(printString, 10000);

var printString = function() {
    console.log("hello world");
}
```

The first argument is the function or operation you wish to perform and the second is the interval (in milliseconds) between each execution.